# Foreach is underlined when trying to change my database

Tags: c#, database, linq-to-sql, foreach

I don't have a clue what is going on here, wondering if someone can solve my issue.
I am trying to replace all of the First_names with the teacher_Id of <= 2 to "Jerry" in my database.

The foreach is underlined with an error and says:

> Cannot convert type 'string' to 'Project.TeacherDetail'

```
private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ProjectDBDataContext Context = new ProjectDBDataContext();
        var r =
                from b in Context.TeacherDetails
                where b.TeacherId <= 2
                select b.First_Name ;

           foreach (TeacherDetail b in r)            
              b.First_Name = "Jerry";

           Context.SubmitChanges();


    }
```

Any help would be appreciated a lot

Comment: What is the implementation of `TeacherDetail` class?

Comment: change `select b.First_Name` to `select b`

Comment: TeacherDetails is my table within my database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming;

```
public class TeacherDetails 
{
    public string First_Name { get; set; }
    //....
}
```

You need to implement it like this;

```
private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ProjectDBDataContext Context = new ProjectDBDataContext();
    var r =
            from b in Context.TeacherDetails
            where b.TeacherId <= 2
            select b; //Remove .First_Name here

    foreach (TeacherDetail b in r)            
        b.First_Name = "Jerry";

    Context.SubmitChanges();
}
```

You were selecting a `string` with `select b.First_Name`, whereas you would then loop over it as if it were a `TeacherDetail` in your `foreach`.

Comment: Sorry I'm not 100% what you are tell me to do. Are you asking me to create a new class outside of the button?

Comment: No, I was just assuming that `First_Name` is implemented as a string. just change `b.First_Name` to `b`, as stated.